How to correctly annotate child container classes in Python?
Context
Imagine you implement a base container class MyList and a child class MyList2
from collections import UserList
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Self

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyList(UserList[T]):
    
    def __add__(self, other: MyList) -> Self:
        return type(self)(val + other[idx] for idx, val in enumerate(self))

class MyList2(MyList[T], Generic[T]):
    pass

Now let us consider the following variables,
a = MyList([1, 2, 3]) # MyList[int]
b = MyList([0.5, 1.5, 2.5]) # MyList[float]
c = MyList2([1, 2, 3]) # MyList2[int]

It turns out d and e here below will be inferred by a static type checker as,
d = a + b # inferred as MyList[int], I want MyList[float]
e = c + b # inferred as MyList2[int], I want MyList2[float]

that is, they are considered as the same type (the container type and also the subscription type int) as the left variables of + due to the use of type(self) in the implementation. At runtime this is not really a problem, but you will have to help the type checker almost each time you call __add__ so this is not optimal.
This behaviour can be avoided if you implement something like
class MyList3(UserList[T]):
    
    def __add__(self, other: MyList3):
        return MyList3(val + other[idx] for idx, val in enumerate(self))

class MyList4(MyList3[T], Generic[T]):
    pass

so that
f = MyList3([1, 2, 3]) # MyList3[int]
g = MyList3([0.5, 1.5, 2.5]) # MyList3[float]
h = f + g # MyList3[float]

but this would also mean you could not create the same container type as your arguments (if f and g were MyList4 instances, h would still be of MyList3 type). You have to live with the parent base class. You will need to implement __add__ for all child classes to overcome this, and this would be tedious and you will repeat yourself unncessarily (compared to the type(self) approach) just to get the correct type hints.
Question
So how can you implement it so that, for any child container class L of MyList, you can get
__add__(L[int], L[float]) -> L[float]
__add__(L[float], L[npt.NDArray[np.floating]]) -> L[npt.NDArray[np.floating]]
...
__add__(L[A], L[B]) -> L[C] # if __add__(A, B) -> C, i.e. if adding type A object and type B object gives type C object


I do not really understand what you are asking for. Can you give more examples of what you pass in, expect/want to have vs. what you actually have, and what is C in your last example?

@Daraan I editted the question. Is it more clear now?

At least for the int/float part, I think you should be able to keep the type-you want if you put said variable on the left-hand side. Maybe if A and B have good typed __add__ methods maybe a type-checker could infer the return type implicitly, in such cases you could consider not annotating the return type.

@Daraan a static type checker (in my case mypy) would still infer the return type as Self even without the explicit annotation.
